# SQLite, dabase.insert() returns -1

Tags: android, sqlite

i am facing a problem with my code, when i am trying to insert information in my database using the insert(tablename, null, contenValues) function it return -1.
Here is my code

```
    public void addItem(View view) {
        String t1 = nameEt.getText().toString();
        String t2 = priceEt.getText().toString();

        if(t1.isEmpty() || t2.isEmpty()) {
            Functions.message(this, "Enter both fields");
        }
        else {
            long id = helper.insertData(t1, t2);
            if (id<=0) {
                Functions.message(this, "Unsuccessful");
            }
            else {
                Functions.message(this, "Inserted!");
            }
        }
```

---

```
   class myDataBaseAdapter {
                private myDataBaseHelper myhelper;
                myDataBaseAdapter(Context context) {
                    myhelper = new myDataBaseHelper(context);
                }

                long insertData(String name, String price) {

                    long id;

                    SQLiteDatabase db = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(myDataBaseHelper.NAME, name);
                    contentValues.put(myDataBaseHelper.PRICE, price);
                    id = db.insert(myDataBaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
                    return id;
                }

                static class myDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

                    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDataBase";
                    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "myTable";
                    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
                    private static final String UID = "_id";
                    private static final String NAME = "Name";
                    private static final String PRICE = "Price";
                    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_NAME+" ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NAME+" VARCHAR(255), "+PRICE+" VARCHAR(255));";
                    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
                    private Context context;

                    myDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
                        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                        this.context = context;
                        Functions.message(context, "constructor called");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                        try {
                            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
                            Functions.message(context, "onCreate called");
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            Functions.message(context, ""+e);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                        try {
                            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
                            Functions.message(context, "onUpgrade called");
                            onCreate(db);
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            Functions.message(context, ""+e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

The message function is just a simple toast message to help me.
I am using android studio if this makes any difference.
how can i correct this

Comment: First change `if (id<=0)` to `if (id<0)` because `insert()` returns `-1` if an error occurred or a value `>=0` (the new id) if it is successfull.

Comment: Replace `insert` with `insertOrThrow`.

Comment: replacing insert with insertOrThrow didn't fix the problem, now the app crashes.

Comment: Post the error log when you use insertOrThrow.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreate()` creates a table called `myDataBase` while your insert is attempted on `myTable`. Change

```
"CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_NAME+"
```

to

```
"CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"
```

You can uninstall your app to recreate the database.

While there, consider removing all those `catch (SQLException)` blocks - if there were problems with the SQL, they would be hidden. You want to detect programming errors as early as possible.